# Best practice to find out if SwiftyJSON dictionary has key

Tags: swift, swifty-json

I'm trying to find a way to get the value of a key in a [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON) dictionary and return a default string, if the key is not set. The following example works fine, but I'm not really satisfied. Do you know a more elegant way?

#### Example:

```
let users: JSON = [
    ["id": 1, "name": "one"],
    ["id": 2],
    ["id": 3, "name": "three"]
]
    
for (key: String, user: JSON) in users {      
    println(user.object.objectForKey("name") != nil
        ? user["name"].stringValue
        : "default")
}
```

Comment: did you ever find a solution to that? thanks!

Comment: @Hannes: no, unfortunately not

Comment: I think there are better JSON libraries out there nowadays, in most use cases ObjectMapper works a lot better since it'll create objects instead of having to slug through all kinds of stringly typed optional dictionary items.

Answer (score 28):

The [latest](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON#existance) version of SwiftyJSON has the `exists()` function.

**NOTE**: Their latest documentation does not reflect the code very well... The actual method is `exists()`

```
// Returns boolean

json["name"].exists()
```

Comment: At least in version 2.3.3 and version 3 of SwiftyJSON that method is still `isExists()`

Comment: SwiftyJSON (3.1.3) uses `.exists()` syntax.

Comment: Not work for me, print true even when value is null.

Answer (score 9):

It seems, SwiftyJSON sets the `error` property when `subscript` non-existing key.

So, this should works:

```
for (key: String, user: JSON) in users {
    let name = user["name"];
    println(name.error == nil ? name.stringValue : "default")
}
```

For example: w/ Version 6.1.1 (6A2006), SwiftyJSON github current master:

```
let users: JSON = [
    ["id": 1, "name": "one"],
    ["id": 2],
    ["id": 3, "name": NSNull()],
    ["id": 4, "name": "four"],
]

for (key: String, user: JSON) in users {
    let name = user["name"];
    name.isEmpty
    println(name.error == nil ? name.stringValue : "default")
}
```

prints:

```
one
default

four
```

Comment: I also tried this way, but it directly crashes after `let name = user["name"];`.

Comment: At least, it works in my environment, as added to the answer. Please provides more info, what error?

Comment: Your version (http://imgur.com/ZDiyRds) works until the second user. Then it can't find the getter (http://imgur.com/GgjiEUA). Do you use a different master? https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON/blob/master/Source/SwiftyJSON.swift

Answer (score 7):

If you need to check if a `SwiftyJSON` dictionary has a key, you can compare it with `JSON.null` as follows:

```
user["name"] == JSON.null // true if the key does not exist
```

Using that method, your code could look like this:

```
let users: JSON = [
    ["id": 1, "name": "one"],
    ["id": 2],
    ["id": 3, "name": "three"]
]

for (key, user) in users {
    print(user["name"] != JSON.null ? user["name"].stringValue : "default")
}
```

If you just want to provide a default value, then you can use the [Nil Coalescing Operator](http://www.codingexplorer.com/nil-coalescing-swift/) in Swift (`??`) like this:

```
let users: JSON = [
    ["id": 1, "name": "one"],
    ["id": 2],
    ["id": 3, "name": "three"]
]

for (key, user) in users {
    print(user["name"].string ?? "default")
}
```

SwiftJSON provides the `string` method, which returns an optional value (`String?`), contrary to `stringValue` which always returns a `String`.

Answer (score 1):

Objects of type `JSON` have a calculated property called `null`. This returns `NSNull` if the element requested does not exist, `nil` if it does. You can therefore test for the existence of a specific object by extracting it from its parent `JSON` and testing to see if the `null` property exists. I personally handle it like this:

```
let object = json["key"]
if object.null == nil {
    // Do something with 'object'
} else {
    // Key does not exist - handle the error
}
```

In your specific case, you could use this:

```
for (key: String, user: JSON) in users {
    let name = user.object.objectForKey("name")
    println(name.null == nil ? name.stringValue : "default")
}
```

...but since we know we're looking for a string we can cut that down even further. All you actually need to do is drop the 'Value' part of `stringValue`, since `string` will return nil if it cannot generate a string from its content. Also, check out the nil coalescence operator `??`. It's designed to provide a default for optional variables, so try this:

```
for (key: String, user: JSON) in users {
    println(user["name"].string ?? "default")
}
```

Nice and compact!

Comment: Oops, just realized my answer is almost the same as the last part you wrote. Well, for easier access, I guess I'll leave the answer

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, this works:

```
let users: JSON = [
    ["id": 1, "name": "one"],
    ["id": 2],
    ["id": 3, "name": "three"]
]

for jsonDict in users.arrayValue {      
    println(jsonDict["name"].string ?? "default")
}
```

To explain, you want to cast the `JSON` object to the types you expect to get. If you want the type to always succeed (not optional), use `xxxValue`. Hence, we cast the root object using `arrayValue`.

`arrayValue` returns `[JSON]`, which we traverse in the loop. We don't need to case the `jsonDict: JSON` to object, as SwiftyJSON is smart enough to assume it is a dict from the subscript operators.

Finally, trying to fetch a key from the dict, then checking if the key can be retrieved as a string using `.string`, which is an optional. Use null coalescing to assign a default value.

Please see the SwiftJSON doc for `string` and `stringValue`

Answer (score -1):

**Note: This answer is no longer valid**

Seems like the perfect use of `if let` syntax. Because accessing the subscript will return an optional, bind it to a variable in an `if let` block. This will tell you wether or not the key was in the `JSON`.

```
if let name = user["name"] {    // returns optional
    // user["name"] was non-nil, is now stored in ``name""
    // do something with ``name""
} 
else {
    // user did not have key "name"
    // here would be the place to return "default"
    // or do any other error correction if the key did not exist
}
```

Comment: No, this is invalid: http://i.imgur.com/ST0MgLX.png. Making a cast as JSON crashes too: http://i.imgur.com/wpwlI6H.png